# How can I suppress filename extensions at the command line interpreter and batch files?

Tags: unix, shell, dos, informix, batch-file

Example: I have a file: FILENAME.EXT and would like to extract FILENAME without the .EXT
I want to be able to use the extensionless filename for a command which only accepts filenames without its extensions. I have a utility called BCHECK which accepts as its argument a filename with no extensions. Using BCHECK *. does not work because all the files have .DAT or .IDX extensions. These files are constantly being renamed, thus I need to provide BCHECK with the new filenames without having to manually enter them.

Comment: Removing the "unix" tag as this seems to be about DOS/Windows batch files only.

Comment: @David: My app runs both in UNIX and DOS so I need to know for both.

Comment: Will `basename` work for you on Unix?

Comment: Interesting, the first batch question I see that refers to DOS and now Windows batch files.

Answer (score 2):

The Unix command for this is `basename`.

Answer (score 1):

For DOS batch files you can look at parameters [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).  For example, the following command displays the filename without extension for the 0 parameter, which is the name of the batch file.

```
echo %~n0
```

UPDATE:
Here's an example that can be added to a batch file.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.dat) DO bcheck -y %%~nf
```

This command will run `bcheck -y BASENAME` for each file with a `.dat` extension in the current directory.  The command is a for loop that contains a parameter `%%f`.  The `%%f` parameter contains the file's full name.  For each file matching `*.dat`, it will run the command after the DO keyword.  The `%%~nf` indicates to to use the basename (`~n`) from the parameter (`%%f`).

Comment: @bobs: That didn't work in DOS 6.22..I have about 30 files with .DAT extensions in directory C:\DBFILES.. I have a utility called BCHECK.EXE which needs as its argument the basename of the 30 .DAT files, example: 'bcheck -y BASENAME' so can you provide me with a working example?

Comment: @bobs: Nope, that didn't work within a batch script either, bcheck responded with: File %~nf not found. Remember, this is Pure DOS 6.22 not Windows cmd.exe command interpreter.

Comment: @bobs: Is there any way of subscripting the 8.3 filename like [1,8]?

Comment: @Frank, no, there isn't. Not in DOS, at least.

Comment: So I have looked at several DOS batch utilities and tricks in MGD and other DOS-related websites, but none of these work!.. can anyone think of a clever way for executing a utility which takes as its argument basenames of all files within a directory?