# In a batch file, how do I get a file name from a file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a batch file that requires the user to enter a file path. Later on in the file I want to isolate just the filename and extention from the path, ie anything after the last '\'.

```
set FILEPATH=\\srv-01\My Docs\Templates\My SpreadSheet.xls
...
set FILENAME=???
```

What do i need to set FILENAME to in order for it to equal 'My SpreadSheet.xls'?

Hopefully this is fairly simple to do. Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432851/dos-bat-file-equivalent-to-unix-basename-command     you'd need `for /F %i in ("c:\foo\bar.txt") do @echo %~nxi`

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof: That question is about DOS (Real DOS) and your little code snippet fails for paths with spaces...

Comment: @user1055650: The tags dos+windows implies Win9x but I assume that you actually mean WinNT+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
set FILEPATH=\\srv-01\My Docs\Templates\My SpreadSheet.xls
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do set "FILEPATH=%%~nxA"
echo.%FILEPATH%
```

Comment: It's slow because cmd.exe is actually looking for the file on `"\\srv-01\My Docs"`, even though it doesn't really have to (or I'm not sure why it does). I'll bet that you don't really have such a server or file (it's faster if the location exists).

Comment: Oh that explains it. Thanks for your help there Michael.