# Change latter part of file name, but not extension, in batch

Tags: batch-file, command, timestamp

I'm trying to rename the latter part of a file, before the extension, in a `batch script`.
For instance:

```
block1.txt --> block1-%mydate%-%mytime%.txt

block2.zip --> block2-%mydate%-%mytime%.txt
```

The file name is passed to the program as `%1`. Only one file name will be changed per run. The program is intended to append a time-stamp to the end of a file, in the form of `MMDDYYYY-HHMM.`

The first part of the program produces the expression `%mydate%-%mytime%`.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in a generic and consistently functional way.

Any help?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Computation of date and time strings? or parsing out the name components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean: **FileName-MMDDYYYY-HHSS.***

```
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=/:. " %%a in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set newFileName=%~n1-%%a%%b%%c-%%d%%f%~x1
ren "%~1" "%newFileName%"
```

Or did you mean: **FileName-MMDDYYYY-HHMM.***

```
for /f "tokens=2-6 delims=/:. " %%a in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set newFileName=%~n1-%%a%%b%%c-%%d%%e%~x1
ren "%~1" "%newFileName%"
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows** here is what **@hobodave** answered to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432851/dos-bat-file-equivalent-to-unix-basename-command/3432895#3432895):

**For command-line**

```
for /F %i in ("c:\foo\bar.txt") do @echo %~ni
```

output: `bar`

**For .bat Files**

```
set FILE=bar
for /F %%i in ("%FILE%") do @echo %%~ni
```

output: `bar`

Further Reading:

http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm

**For Unix**

You can use the **basename** command. It will clear path and extension from a given path.

```
basename /foo/bar/arch.zip .zip
```

Will output

```
arch
```

Basename manual: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?basename