# Rename multiple files in a directory using batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I have about 1000 images and they have name like "IMG-12223". I want to rename them to 1 2 3 4 ... 1000. How can I do that. I have  written a batch script which list the files but I don't know how to rename each file. e.g. rename first image with name "IMG-12223" to 1 , second image with name "IMG-23441" to 2 and so on ...

```
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    echo %c% 
)
```

Comment: Just a hint: Freeware multimedia viewer [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) has built-in a [batch rename](http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/renamers/ht/irfanviewrename.htm) feature to rename images with a counter. Also shareware file manager [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) has a [multi-rename](http://www.ghisler.com/advanced.htm#tutorial_rename) feature with even more options and very easy to use. It does not make sense in my opinion using a batch file for such a file renaming task not being executed automatically as scheduled task.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the script. Just put the script in your folder and run it.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *') do (
  if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" (
    ren "%%i" "!a!" 
    set /a a+=1
 ) 
)
```

If you want to keep the extensions, i.e. rename "IMG-12223.jpg", "IMG-12224.jpg", etc to "1.jpg", "2.jpg", etc, you may use the following script.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
  ren "%%i" "!a!.jpg" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

[**Update**] Here're explanations for the lines mentioned in Jack's comment.

- `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

In general, we want the variable `a` to be delayed expansion when it's executed but not the line is read. Without it, the variable `a` cannot get its increased value but always 1.

For the detail of EnableDelayedExpansion, please refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/2749114.

- `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.jpg')`

Here `dir` with `/b` option, lists only file names of all jpg files.

The `for` loop traverses and renames all jpg files.

For the `delims` option, since the default delimiter character is a space, without the option `delims=`, it fails with the image files with spaces in the file names. I.E. for an image file named "img with spaces.jpg", without the option, the value of `%%i` is "img" but not the whole name "img with spaces.jpg", which is incorrect.

For `for` loop, please refer to the page http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html.

- `if not "%%~ni"=="%~n0"`

I have change it to `if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0"` to be more accurate. And the codes attached have been updated.

It's actually used to avoid to rename the bat file itself. If we limit the renaming only upon "jpg" files, then the line is not needed.

`%%~nxi` is the file name with extension for each file traversed. And `%~nx0` is the running bat file with extension. For details, please refer to the page [DOS BAT file equivalent to Unix basename command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432851/dos-bat-file-equivalent-to-unix-basename-command).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please explain the following lines "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" , "for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.jpg')" , if not "%%~ni"=="%~n0"

Comment: Sure, I have just improved the script, and also add explanations to the lines you mentioned. Actually you may also change the script a bit to take the directory of your images as a parameter.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for a batch script. A simple one liner from the command line can do the job :-)

I use DIR /B to generate the list of files, piped to FINDSTR to number the files, all enclosed withn FOR /F to parse the result and perform the rename.

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %A in ('dir /b *.jpg^|findstr /n "^"') do @ren "%B" "%A%~xB"
```

Double the percents if you want to put the command in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have pair of namevalues in a text file then loop values and do the magic. Namevalues are separated by empty spaces. This allows you to map old->new filenames accordingly. Or you keep idx+1 counter and use it for new filenames.

**keyvalue.bat**

```
@echo off
set idx=0
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in (keyvalue.txt) do call :PROCESS "%%A"  "%%B"
GOTO :END

:PROCESS
set var1=%~1
set var2=%~2
set /A idx=%idx%+1
echo %var1% goes to %var2% (%idx%)
GOTO :EOF

:END
pause
```

**keyvalue.txt**

```
file888.dat  newfile1.dat
file333.dat  newfile2.dat
file9.dat    newfile3.dat
file01.dat   newfile4.dat
```