# Bulk extension changer

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to make `.bat` file which will be changing all files on all discs with extension `.xxx` to extension `.yyy`. It's just an example because I will want to add more file extensions like: change all `.aaa`, `.bbb`, `.ccc`, etc. files to extension `.ggg`.

Comment: Well thank you too, but no one will give you the code so easily. Why ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583161/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-batch-script

Answer (score 1):

You can download [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Rename-file-extensions-in-c8e7ab6e) script from Microsoft's Script Center. It can change file extensions in bulk:

> This batch script can be used to change file extensions in bulk. File extensions are renamed for all matching files in the current folder and in all subdirectories.It supports the following.1. Change extension for all the files in the current folder and all sub folders.

You can also use `cmd` or file renaming utilities.

You can do it using `rename` command, the general form is:

`RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2`

Or

`REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2`

For example;

`REN *.xxx *.yyy`

And also there are some file renaming utilities that you can use for the same:

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php),

[Bulk Extension Changer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/b-e-c/)

For more detail please refer to this [link](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-file-extension/).

Comment: Could you please just write for me command to do it for the whole disc C? I mean this one: RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2