# Run uic for all .ui files in directory using windows batch

Tags: qt, batch-file, windows-7

I can get a list of Qt `.ui` files like so:

```
D:\programing\qtproject\ui\designer>dir *.ui /B
main.ui
mainmenu.ui
mainwindow.ui
```

And what I do right now is that I manually run `uic` for every one of them, because IDE I'm using (QtCreator, ironically the one IDE that should be perfectly compatible with Qt) is not capable of that.

So can I run `uic` with a list of files obtained from `dir *.ui /B`? I would prefer if this worked recursively on all subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I cracked it using some helpful answers:

```
@echo off
rem Runs uic command over all files in all subdirectories
rem For loop arguments explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3433012/607407
rem start command arguments explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/154090/607407
rem       /B is why the start creates no additional windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/324549/607407

for /f %%F in ('dir *.ui /S /B') do start "" /B "uic" %%F -o %%~dpFui_%%~nF.h
```

To disable the recursion (subdirectories), remove the `/S` parameter in the `dir` command.