# Last index of a character in an input string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script running in windows. Every time the batch script is invoked an input path is provided as a parameter. I need to extract the folder name from the path.For that i need to get the last index of "/" from the path and then take a substring from that path until the end of the string.

Suppose I have a string /home/home1/home2/home3

The output I require is home3. Is there any way to extract the same.

Comment: In Windows you should use the backslash as path separator, as some commands might have trouble otherwise...

Comment: Do you want _The last index of "/" from the path_ or you want _The last folder name from the path_? The question title indicate that the important data is the _index of a character_, but the last folder _can be extracted_ without using an index! I suggest you to focus your questions on the _real problem_ (like "folder name") and not insert unrelated data (like "index of a char").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For plain DOS/Windows batch files, this should work:

```
set FILE="c:\foo\bar.txt"
for /F %%i in ("%FILE%") do @echo %%~ni
```

That comes from [DOS BAT file equivalent to Unix basename command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432851/dos-bat-file-equivalent-to-unix-basename-command)

Windows PowerShell and the Unix shell offer other alternatives.

Comment: Thank you Todd! :)

Comment: Not only is /F not necessary, it will cause problems if the path has spaces in it, unless DELIMS is set to nothing. Also, it should be `%%~nxi`, as folder names can include dots.

Comment: This will fail if the original path has a trailing backslash. There are additional esoteric edge cases. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39547800/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a string representing a folder path, and you want the name of the right most folder within the path. CMD.EXE provides convenient tools to work with file/folder paths, so there is no need to search for the last `\`.

You don't state where the string resides. Most likely it is either 1) in a batch parameter from a CALL to a batch script or :function, or 2) within an environment variable. I will assume a parameter, and show a succession of solutions, each one better (more robust) than the prior one. At the very end I will show a slight twist to adapt to working with an environment variable.

So if parameter `%1` contains `/home/home1/home2/home3`, then all you need is `%~n1`.

But folder names can include dots, and the text after the last dot is considered to be an extension. So you need the `x` modifier as well to include the extension. For example, if `%1` contains `/home.1/home.2/home.3`, then `%~nx` will yield `home.3`. It works just as well if there is no extension.

But folder names can include a poison character like `&`, so you should enclose the string in quotes: `"%~nx1"`. If you are assigning the result to a variable, then you should enclose the entire assignment in quotes: `set "folder=%~nx1"`. The value will not include the quotes, so be sure to add quotes when expanding the variable: `"%folder%"`, or else use delayed expansion `!folder!`.

But sometimes people include a trailing backslash when passing a folder path, as in `\home1\home2\home3\`. The trailing backslash positively indicates that the path is to a folder, but `%~nx1` will yield nothing. There is a simple trick using a FOR loop and an appended dot to solve this.

```
for %%F in (%1.) do set "folder=%%~nxF"
```

Note that FOR variables use the exact same modifiers as parameters. The appended dot elegantly solves the problem in a tricky way. If there is a trailing backslash, then the dot represents the "current" directory from that postion. The expansion modifiers automatically normalize the result into a canonical form, which yields the correct answer. But it also works if there is not a trailing backslash. File and folder names are not allowed to end with a dot or a space, and the expansion normalization will strip the trailing dot.

There are a few other esoteric cases dealing with UNC paths and long paths that are solved by adding the `~f` modifier to convert `%1` into the full canonical path.

**Here is the ultimate solution that should "always" work with batch parameter `%1`.**

```
for %%F in ("%~f1.") do set "folder=%%~nxF"
```

I put the word "always" in quotes because it is possible for the code to fail, but it would require the end user doing something stupid like passing `"c:\This"^&"that\"`. In this case, the correct thing to do is simply pass `"c:\This&that\"`.

Note that the passed path could be the root of a volume, like "c:\". In this case the result is an empty string, which is correct - there is no folder name.

***How to work with an environment variable instead***

Suppose you have variable `folderPath` that contains the path string. If you know that the value does not contain any quotes, and it is not a UNC or long path, then you can simply use:

```
for %%F in ("%folderPath%.") do set "folder=%%~nxF"
```

But that can fail in multiple ways if the value already contains quotes, or if it is a UNC or long path. The solution is to add an extra FOR /F loop coupled with delayed expansion to safely transfer the value into a FOR variable. Then the `~f` modifier can be used as before. But paths can include the `!` character, and FOR variable expansion will strip any `!` if delayed expansion is enabled. So delayed expansion must be strategically toggled on and off.

**Here is the ultimate solution for working with a variable**

I'm assuming that delayed expansion is currently off.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ("!folderPath!") do (
  endlocal
  for %%F in ("%%~fA.") do set "folder=%%~nxF"
)
```

I'm not aware of any scenarios where this last code can fail.